# How to prevent Visual Studio 2008 C compiler from stopping when some errors occur?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I want to see how many errors I have in my source code but compiler stops when it encounters some errors (but not all).

Is there a way to make Visual Studio to continue compiling until it finds all errors in code?

(Visual Studio 2008 is mandatory)

**EDIT:** I need to do this for the following reason. We have a c99 code base but customer demands an older version which Visual Studio 2008 should be able to compile. Thus we want to see how many errors occur because of the difference between c99 and c89 (not c 89 but a version in between for Visual Studio 2008).

Comment: Use VS 2017. The IDE is good in spotting errors while editing. And you don't use a compiler from the stone age.

Comment: It already does that. Except it won't link and it stops after a C++ compilation with errors before continuing with a C compilation.

Comment: When you have long lists of errors in a file, it is not unusual that many of them are *false positives*, depending on a single earlier error. Therefore it's often not very useful to see all errors since they might not really exist.

Comment: It does not really make sense. Say for instance you didn't close a curly brace or a double quote. That makes all the rest of your code wrong. Would the hundreds of errors be relevant? No.

Comment: @spectras I edited my question to answer yours.

Comment: Can't you create the current code as a *library* that is then linked with a simple front-end application using the older IDE? That would make more sense (to me) than having to refactor your code into something to be supported by older and outdated environments.

Comment: Still holds. Say you `#include <inttypes.h>` or `#include <stdbool.h>`, would the thousands of errors about bool or missing integer types be relevant? The point is in a translation unit, code defines how to interpret the code that follows. Errors in the code throw off that interpretation, making what follows meaningless.

Comment: @ozgur Sadly, even if you could force the compiler to continue you wouldn't be getting a good result (to gauge how problematic getting the c89 version to compile is/would be). As pointed out above, you will run into lots of false positives (a error prevents a variable from being declared, which turns a set of statements incompilable, which cause the function to lack the correct "return" statement etc...) While also hiding other issues (in the set of statements rendered incompileable due to the not-defined variable, there are 5 more errors which only get uncovered once you fix the first error)

Comment: the number of errors from one compilation is pretty much useless. Fixing one error can also fix the next 1000, or can in turn expose another 100 errors.

Comment: @manni66 VS 2017 in C mode is still from the stone age. It is almost 20 years old.

Comment: @Lundin: It does have C99 headers, unlike VS2008. That is the bigger objection here - VS2017 will probably produce _more_ errors, because VS2008 already gives up in the preprocessor stage. Missing a header is only a single error.

Comment: @MSalters Perhaps one day it will even be a conforming hosted implementation of C99. Maybe even standard C, though that is probably asking too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Thus we want to see how many errors occur because of the difference between c99 and c89*"

I don't think you can do that. For example:

```
int example(void)
{
    getsomething();
    int i;            // <== invalid in C89
```

The above example is just 1 error but will generate lots of errors because `i` is not declared in the remainder.